# The Element Does not Shrink and it copy the last index

Tags: java, arrays

I was not able to shrink the specific element in an array. It copy the last element of the array and it will stay the same size.

Output:

**1. Ramburat - 100 - PASSED**

**2. Ramburat - 100 - PASSED**

Possible Output

**1. Ramburat - 100 - PASSED**

Source code for Deletion of an Element

```
   public static void deleteStudent(String full_name)
{
    int found = 1;
    int delindex = -1;
    for (int i= 0; i<count; i++)
    {
        if(name[i].equalsIgnoreCase(full_name))
        {
            // If matched then change the value of found to 1
            found = 1;
            // Store index of student to be deleted
            delindex = i;
            break;
            
        }
    }
    
    // If student name is not found then value of flag remains unchanged
            // Display the error that student not found
            if(found == -1)
                System.out.println("Error : No such student found!!!");
            else
            {
                // Push all elements from index i+1 to last, 1 step back
                for(int i=delindex; i<count-1; i++)
                {
                    name[i] = name[i+1];
                    grade[i] = grade[i+1];
                    result[i] = result[i+1];
                }
                System.out.println("Student Details deleted Successfully.");
            }
}
```

Here in this source code, the last part of my code I used to push back the data in order for the chosen name should be removed. but it still in the same size and it prints double.

Source code for ShowAllStudent

```
 public static void showAllStudents()
{
    // if count is 0 then no students in the list
    if(count == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("There are no registered student in ISCP");
    }
    else
    {
        // Loop from index 0 to count of arrays
        for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i+1+". " + name[i] + " - " + grade[i] + " - " + result[i]);
        
        }
    }
}
```

Source code for Public static void main

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    

    enlistStudent("Doyoung", 50);
    enlistStudent("Ramburat", 100);

    deleteStudent("Doyoung");
    showAllStudents();

}
```

Comment: In Java, once you have created an array, its size cannot be changed. If you need to remove an element from an array and change the size of the array, then you must create a new array of the desired size and copy elements from the old to the new array. In practice you would use an `ArrayList` instead of an array and doing this manually.

Comment: It doesn't help that you've provided *bits* of code instead of a [mcve], but fundamentally: what do you expect `count` to be after the `deleteStudent` call, and what have you found it to be in the debugger?